# Data in table format with Header & Row

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vG6tY/)

I have following array : -

```
var data = [{
    "recordno": "001",
        "firstname": "Brock",
        "middlename": "Edward",
        "lastname": "Lesnar",
        "gender": "male",
        "dateofbirth": "1980-01-01T20:20:19.198Z",
        "dateofdeath": null,
        "status": "archive"
}, {
    "recordno": "002",
        "firstname": "John",
        "middlename": "E",
        "lastname": "Cena",
        "gender": "male",
        "dateofbirth": "1980-01-01T20:20:19.198Z",
        "dateofdeath": null,
        "status": "archive"
}];
```

I want to show it in Table format in my HTML. My issue is the table header & the row data do not match. You can check the fiddle for demo.

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do anything in the function.

[JS FIDDLE UPDATE](http://jsfiddle.net/vG6tY/1/)

**JS**

```
function TableController($scope) {
    $scope.rows = data;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="TableController">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat='(key, value) in rows[0]'>{{key}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat='row in rows'>
            <td ng-repeat='cell in row'>{{cell}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Works Nice...How to show columns as they are in `data`? I mean..`recordno` should come 1st....`firstname` 2nd & so on.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it.